# Click on a place on GoogleMap for android (not PlacePicker)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to find a trigger for an event once clicked on one of the pre-existing "places" or business icons in google maps. I want to know if there's something similar to the onMarkerClickListener something as an onPlaceClickListener that would retrieve the placeId or something?

I know that placePicker intent/activity is inbuilt, but I'm trying my own thing.

Comment: You edited this post 4 times while I was trying to read it, try to ask without edits?

Comment: Wow, that's what the edit button is for though.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that the Google API lists an [OnPOIClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PointOfInterest) Interface that does what I need.